# Keep receiving this error "Failed to initialize detector". Am I not loading the tflite model correctly?

Tags: java, android, android-camerax, google-mlkit

I am trying to setup an ImageAnalyzer with my Android app so I can run object classification using Google's ML Kit API. The issue I am currently facing, as the title suggests, is constantly seeing the error "Failed to initialize detector".

I've reread [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/custom-models/android) about three times now and followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65446130/it-requires-specifying-normalizationoptions-metadata-to-preprocess-input-images) about someone facing the same error (although for a different reason) to no avail. I've also made sure everything with the CameraX API (except the ImageAnalyzer code that I will show in a second) works as expected.

As mentioned in the ML Kit documentation, here is the code I have regarding setting up a `LocalModel`, a `CustomObjectDetectorOptions`, and an `ObjectDetector`:

```java
        LocalModel localModel = new LocalModel.Builder()
                .setAssetFilePath("mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quantized_1_metadata_1.tflite")
                .build();
        CustomObjectDetectorOptions customObjectDetectorOptions =
                new CustomObjectDetectorOptions.Builder(localModel)
                        .setDetectorMode(CustomObjectDetectorOptions.STREAM_MODE)
                        .enableClassification()
                        .setClassificationConfidenceThreshold(0.5f)
                        .setMaxPerObjectLabelCount(3)
                        .build();
        ObjectDetector objectDetector = ObjectDetection.getClient(customObjectDetectorOptions);
```

Here is the ImageAnalyzer code I have, which basically makes a call to the ML Kit API by way of the `processImage` helper method:

```java
    // Creates an ImageAnalysis for analyzing the camera preview feed
        ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setTargetResolution(new Size(224, 224))
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .build();
        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
                new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
                    @Override
                    public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy imageProxy) {
                        @SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError") Image mediaImage =
                                imageProxy.getImage();
                        if (mediaImage != null) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Obtained ImageProxy object");
                            processImage(mediaImage, imageProxy)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<List<DetectedObject>>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<List<DetectedObject>> task) {
                                    imageProxy.close();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Here is the `processImage` helper method, where I actually call `objectDetector.process(...)`, the line of code that actually runs the tflite model.

```java
    private Task<List<DetectedObject>> processImage(Image mediaImage, ImageProxy imageProxy) {
        InputImage image =
                InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage,
                        imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());
        return objectDetector.process(image)
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        String error = "Failed to process. Error: " + e.getMessage();
                        Log.i(TAG, error);
                    }
                })
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<DetectedObject>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<DetectedObject> results) {
                        String success = "Object(s) detected successfully!";
                        Log.i(TAG, success);
                        for (DetectedObject detectedObject : results) {
                            Rect boundingBox = detectedObject.getBoundingBox();
                            Integer trackingId = detectedObject.getTrackingId();
                            for (DetectedObject.Label label : detectedObject.getLabels()) {
                                String text = label.getText();
                                int index = label.getIndex();
                                float confidence = label.getConfidence();
                                Log.i(TAG, "Object detected: " + text + "; "
                                        + "Confidence: " + confidence);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Essentially, once I run the app, logcat just keeps logging these two lines on repeat. I know it means the ImageAnalyzer is continuously trying to analyze the image input, but for some reason the `LocalModel` just cannot process the input

> 2021-01-21 22:02:24.020 9328-9328/com.example.camerax I/MainActivity: Obtained ImageProxy object
>
> 2021-01-21 22:02:24.036 9328-9328/com.example.camerax I/MainActivity: Failed to process. Error: Failed to initialize detector.

I have only just started to work with Android, especially ML in Android, so any sort of help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my issue before anyone answered, but in case anyone who just started to learn Android like me I'll leave my solution here.

Basically, **remember to create an asset folder in the /src/main directory** rather than the /src/androidTest directory :P

Once I did that, the model loaded correctly and now I just have to figure out how to display the results in my application.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Do NOT compress tflite model files (need to call out to developers!)
aaptOptions {
    noCompress "tflite"
}
```

add this line in build gradle for app under android tag